# How to edit information submitted using Django forms in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, django-models

Thank you for the tips. Maybe I can edit this to explain it a little better...

I'm writing an application for Google App Engine where I would like to do a GQL query to get all the evaluations of each type that have already been submitted. I want to allow the user to click on a link to edit each individual evaluation and then submit the change. This is the best way I've found to do it...

```
class EvaluationApproval(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      #search for unapproved general evaluations
      query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM GeneralAssessmentReport WHERE Approved = False")

      if query.count() != 0:
         for item in query:
            #create a link to edit that item
            self.response.out.write('<a href="generalFromApprove?key=%s">%s</a>' % (item.key(), item.Name))


    #do this for each type of evaluation...

    query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM HeadNeck WHERE Approved = False")
    if query.count() != 0:
        for item in query:
            self.response.out.write('<a href="headNeckApprove?key=%s">%s</a>' % (item.key(), item.Name))

    query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM lowerExtremity WHERE Approved = False")
    if query.count() != 0:
        for item in query:
            self.response.out.write('<a href="lowerApprove?key=%s">%s</a>' % (item.key(), item.Name))
```

So, when the user clicks on the link they are directed to...

```
class GeneralFormApprove(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      # get the correct evaluation to approve
      key = self.request.get('key')
      item = GeneralAssessmentReport.get(key)

      #write out the form with key in the form action!
      self.response.out.write('<form method="POST" action="/generalFormApprove?key=%s">' % key)
      self.response.out.write(GeneralAssessmentReportForm(instance=item))

   def post(self):
      # get the key once more
      key = self.request.get('key')

      data = GeneralAssessmentReportForm(data=self.request.POST,instance=GeneralAssessmentReport.get(key))
      if data.is_valid():
         # save the edited evaluation
         entity = data.save(commit=False)
         entity.put()
```

and then have a WhateverFormApprove class for each type of evaluation. Does this make sense and do you have any other ideas to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but storing state in global variables is a bad idea. This is because a subsequent request can be handled by a completely different process.

For better results with this question, you should elide unimportant details from the code that you post. People generally do not want to answer questions where they have to read the entire app. Try to be direct and specific.

Answer (score 0):

for editing existing entities, a good way is to use a url pattern that includes the id of the entity. Upon post, you can use the id to load the entity and then use it in the instance argument for the form.

the url pattern is something like:

```
r'^evaluationapproval/(?P<item_id>[\d]+)/$'


def post(self,item_id=None):
    item = None
    if item_id:
        item = db.get(db.Key.from_path('MyModelKind',int(item_id)))
        #...
```